# Spring javaMail :Inline Images resources display like attachment in web client

Tags: html, spring, jakarta-mail, velocity, mime-message

I use the JavaMail Spring implementation with Velocity template engine. Everything goes well when I send the mails, the pictures are displayed normally and the styles also apply.

The problem that I encounter is that at the reception the email client displays my email as containing attachments, which are actually the images that appear in my email.

I do not understand why the images sent with the mail are seen as pieces joined by the mail client. Somebody can help me please?

This is my code :

```
    final MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();

    final MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message,true, "UTF-8");

    try {
        helper.setFrom(getSystemAddress());
        if (replyTo != null) {
            helper.setReplyTo(replyTo);
        }
        helper.setTo(to);
        helper.setSubject(subject);

        helper.setText(body, isHTML);
        System.out.println("Helper message factory: "+helper);

        FileSystemResource res = new FileSystemResource(new File(MailHandler.class.getResource("logo-email.png").getFile()));
        FileSystemResource res1 = new FileSystemResource(new File(MailHandler.class.getResource("bg-header.PNG").getFile()));

        helper.addInline("cid2", res1);
        helper.addInline("cid1", res);
        mailSender.send(message);
```

Comment: You might want to read about [mcve]. Your code is quite big for a problem, which is very small and related to only parts of your snippet. Please remove some of the resources or use streams to add them (I'd suggest the latter if your Java version allows)

Comment: ok thanks @Clijsters,  i will edit my original post.